# How can I fix "nodata gap" of landsat multispectral band-set in SCP plugin of QGIS v 3.16?

Tags: qgis, mosaic, nodata, image-mosaic, scp

[image]

Two Landsat images of the same date same path but the adjacent row has been atmospherically corrected using DOS (in QGIS) and mosaicked afterward. But this is how I am getting no data value. How can I fix this? There wasn't any gap before I mosaiced them.
**No data value for each of the slides are (-32768)**
Landsat5 path 140 Row 43 and 44
My study area falls in both of the rows.
I am using SCP plugin-Qgis version 3.16

Comment: Is there a data gap in the single files as well, or only after creating the mosaic? How exactly did you mosaic them?

Comment: Add an additional transparency value of 1 to your layer properties before mosaicking.

Comment: Try creating a virtual raster: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html?#build-virtual-raster